# value of years on X axis is not displaying correctly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

value of years on X axis is not displaying correctly . it is displaying years in two parts but I want it as single value

here is what I have tried[pandas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QywOL.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2cpl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert year to date format and plot. Eg.:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({"year" : [2010,2011,2012,2013,2014],
                     "count" :[1000,2200,3890,5600,8000] })

data["year"] = pd.to_datetime(data["year"].astype(str), format="%Y")
ax = data.plot(x="year",y="count")

plt.show()
```